# Why do we boil sugar before priming

Tags: priming-sugar

I read that when priming you need to boil sugar in water. I don't see the point since sugar is considered an anti septic.

What is the purpose of boiling?

Would it be because we need desolved sugar and the water might be contaminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because sugar dissolves much more easily into boiling water, and the syrup that results is easier to incorporate evenly into the beer.  There's a sanitizing component as well, but it's minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Sugar doesn't kill microbes.  Microbes don't grow in it because there's little water around.  But if you have an open bag of sugar (or anything for that matter) sitting around in your kitchen that you dip into every morning for your coffee, there are microbes getting into the bag.
So the boiling does indeed sanitize the solution.
Secondary to that the boiling helps dissolve it faster. You can get the typical amount of priming sugar to dissolve in the water without boiling, but it goes much faster because you are boiling it to sanitize it.